# Get text from textfield

Tags: java, swing, textfield, jtextfield

I'm making a GUI program. In my first program I have the following code:

```
double num1;
num1 = Double.parseDouble(guess.getText());
```

I believe that this code gets the value from the text field and converts it to double.

How can I get the value and convert it to String or Char?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `getText()` already returns a `String`, storing its value as a `String` is trivial.

In order to parse a `double`, you've already done it, just watch for the `NumberFormatException`, in case of invalid input.

To store its value as a `char`, that depends on your requirements. Do you want the first character? Do you require the string to have only a single character? Is any character valid? And so on.

```
// Storing the value as a String.
String value = guess.getText();

// Storing the value as a double.
double doubleValue;
try {
    doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Invalid double String.
}

// Storing the value as a char.
char firstChar = value.length() > 0 ? value.charAt(0) : (char) 0;

// Require the String to have exactly one character.
if (value.length() != 1) {
    // Error state.
}
char charValue = value.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

use String.valueOf() instead of Double.parseDouble() this will help you convert double into string value

Answer (score 0):

The `getText()` already returns the text as String.
Btw, be careful of Exceptions due to parse error. But your on the right track. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `getText()`method returns a String. when you use `.parseDouble` what you are really doing is turning the string the user entered and into a double therefore in the case of a string you do not have to use a .parse method because the value called is already a string. In the case of a character you would  have to use something like this:

```
String text = jTextField1.getText();
if (text.length() > 1 && !text.contains(" ") && !text.contains(",")) {
    //make sure that its length is not over 1, and that it has no spaces and no commas 
    char ch = text;
} else {
    //if a space or comma was found no matter how big the text it will execute the else.. 
    System.out.println("this is not allowed");
    jTextField1.setText("");
}
```

Comment: Your logic for the `char` case seems a bit confusing. What were you trying to achieve?

Comment: @afsantos Something like this: char abc = String;

Answer (score -1):

The `getText()` function already fetches a `String` value from the `Textfield`.

For example:

```
String var = guess.getText();
```

Here, `var` is storing the `String` value received from the `Textfield`.